# facebookConnectPlugin getting two time success call

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am using cordova facebookConnectPlugin in [iOS app.](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

I am trying to login and fetch the user data, but `fbLoginSuccess` fires two times. Which means `facebookConnectPlugin.login` responding two times back to back and I'm not able to find where is the mistake and how to handle this issue.

```
      var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
           alert("UserInfo:");
           alert("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name",["user_birthday"],function (response) {

                                              alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                                     });

           }

          facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],fbLoginSuccess,function (error) { alert(error) }

           );
```

Comment: yes because you are asking for multiple permissions at a time.